# How to import model in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to execute a python file where I want to check if there are new rows in a csv file. If there are new rows, I want to add them to a database.

The project tree is as follows:

[image]

Thus, the file which I want to execute is `check_relations.py` inside `relations` folder.

`check_relations.py` is as follows:

```
from master.models import TraxioRelations

with open('AUTOI_Relaties.csv', 'rb') as tr:
    traxio_relations = tr.readlines()

for line in traxio_relations:
    number = line.split(';')[0]
    number_exists = TraxioRelations.objects.filter(number=number)
    print(number_exists)
```

The model `TraxioRelations` is inside `models.py` in `master` folder.

When I run `python check_relations.py` I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check_relations.py", line 3, in <module>
    from master.models import TraxioRelations
ImportError: No module named master.models
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I import model inside check_relations.py file?

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil The same error `ImportError: No module named models`

Comment: Ignore previous comment. You are running the file externally (not from within django), so `traxio` needs to be in your system path and you should instead do `from traxio.master.models import ...`.

Answer (score 3):

i think the most usable way it is create [commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/)

for example in your master catalog:

```
master /
    management /
        __init__.py
        commands /
            __init__.py
            check_relations.py
```

in *check_relations.py*

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from master.models import TraxioRelations

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'check_relations by file data'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        with open('AUTOI_Relaties.csv', 'rb') as tr:
            traxio_relations = tr.readlines()

        for line in traxio_relations:
            number = line.split(';')[0]
            number_exists = TraxioRelations.objects.filter(number=number)
            print(number_exists)
```

**!** don't forget to change the path to the file `AUTOI_Relaties.csv` or put it to the new dir

and then you can run in shell:

```
./manage.py check_relations
```

Answer (score 1):

When using Django, you are not supposed to run an individual module on its own. See eg https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server.

Comment: I doesn't work. I get the same error `ImportError: No module named traxio.master.models`